# Pie chart with sub-slices per category in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts

I have a sheet that contains a list of books, with metadata about those books. Two columns that exist are the library within which the book is stored, and the condition of the book. I'd like to create a chart showing the number of books in each condition, per the library.

The table looks something like this (excluding other non-relevant metadata)

```
Book     Library     Condition
1        Example1    New
2        Example2    VG
3        Example1    Fair
4        Example3    VG
```

I'd like a table that used the Library column as labels, and had a display for each possible condition in each library. A cluster bar graph would work, but an ideal solution would be something like a double pie chart (where the large slice is the breakdown by the library, and that is the sliced by condition).

Comment: the issue here is that your dataset does not include any numbers which can power the chart directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

- your dataset of **`A1:C`** is not in "good" shape for creating a chart, so first, you will need to re-shape it by adding few formulas in auxiliary columns which you can hide when done
- in cell **E1** paste this formula and create a base pie chart. this will create even ratio between **`Libaries`**. select primary color for each libary and maximze chart style


  ```
  ={"Libaries"\""; {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1&" "; 
    COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>""))));" "))\ 
    UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>""))}}
  ```
- if you got **`#ERROR!`** paste this into **E1** cell:


  ```
  ={"Libaries",""; {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1&" ", 
    COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))))," ")), 
    UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))}}
  ```
- paste this formula in **G1** cell to create labels:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN("×"; 
   TRANSPOSE(REPT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B&"×"; B2:B<>"")); 2))); "×"))
  ```
- then paste this formula in **G2** to create dataset for 2nd chart:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- after this you will need correction formula which can correct position of the first set of pie slices. paste this in **G6** cell and create 2nd pie chart from range **G2:H**. then play with colors and set color of the correction pie on **`None`**


  ```
  =IF(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))>3;
   SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&G1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))*2; 6)
  ```
- when done, overlay 1st chart with 2nd chart
- then paste this formula in **i4** cell (this will be dataset for 3rd chart)


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&I1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- next you need correction again. this time twice. paste this formula in **i2** and **i7**


  ```
  =SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C), 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&I1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''", 0)))
  ```
- now you can construct 3rd pie chart from range **i2:J**. again play with colors and hide correction slices. when done overlay it on top of 1st and 2nd chart
- when done paste this formula in **K4** cell (this will be dataset for the 4th pie chart)


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3), Col3 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0))
  ```
- and again you need to correct the position with this formula pasted in **K2** cell


  ```
  =IF(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))>3;
   SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$C); 
   "select Col3, count(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&K1&"'
    group by Col3 
    label count(Col3)''"; 0)))*2; 6)
  ```
- create 4th pie chart from range **K2:L**, play with colors, hide correction slice, possition it on all previous charts
- if you want to put up some labels then you can **insert drawings** and overlay it once again

[image]

---

## [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUN49WLPdmGQHt7EtoqQ183KQ--7NcKaQS4DUAycC14/edit#gid=1100830887)

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to give this a shot later today, but because of the sheer level of detail you put into answering this, I've gone ahead and accepted your answer.

Comment: I'm having some trouble converting this to use the columns that I have.

For me, `A` is still the book number, but the actual library column is `I` and the condition is `J`.

Using this in `L1`
```={"Libaries",""; {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1&" ", 
  COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(I2:I, I2:I<>""))))," ")), 
  UNIQUE(FILTER(I2:I, I2:I<>""))}}```
Appears to work and gives me the list of libraries.

In `N1`,
```=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(JOIN("×", 
 TRANSPOSE(REPT(UNIQUE(FILTER(I2:I&"×", I2:I<>"")), 2))), "×"))```
builds the headers successfully

Comment: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT($A$2:$J); 
 "select count(Col3), Col3 
  where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&N1&"'
  group by Col3 
  label count(Col3)''"; 0))```
gives me `#N/A`.

Comment: @Tomas if you use range **A:J** every Col2 needs to be Co9 and every Col3 needs to be Col10 - see here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUN49WLPdmGQHt7EtoqQ183KQ--7NcKaQS4DUAycC14/edit#gid=866859629